# MSP430 Low power mode LPM3.5

Tags: msp430

MSP430f6436

I just wanted to know, if the micro controller will go into Low power state (LPM3.5) if we cut the main power supply of the micro controller?

Backup battery is already connected with the internal RTC. And while the RTC is in operation the RTC is active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [User Guide](http://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/slau208),

> LPMx.5 entry and exit is handled differently than the other low power
>   modes. LPMx.5, when used properly, gives the lowest power consumption
>   available on a device. To achieve this, entry to LPMx.5 disables the
>   LDO of the PMM module, removing the supply voltage from the core of
>   the device.

Further, the way to enter this LPM3.5 mode is also described very well in the UG

> The program flow for entering LPMx.5 is: ￼1. Configure I/O
>   appropriately. See the Digital I/O chapter for complete details on
>   configuring I/O for LPMx.5. 
>   • Set all ports to general purpose I/O.
>   Configure each port to ensure no floating inputs based on the
>   application requirements. 
>   • If wakeup from I/O is desired, configure
>   input ports with interrupt capability appropriately.
>   2. If LPM3.5 is available, and desired, enable RTC operation. In addition, configure any RTC interrupts, if desired for LPM3.5 wakeup
>   event. See the RTC Overview chapter for complete details.
>   3. Ensure clock system settings allow LPMx.5 entry according to Table 5-1 in UCS chapter.
>   4. Enter LPMx.5 by setting PMMREGOFF=1 and LPM4 status register bits. The following code example shows how to enter LPMx.5 mode. See the PMM
>   chapter for further details.

Broadly speaking what these two paragraphs mean, is that some amount of SW intervention is required to enter the LMP3.5 mode.

"Cutting" the main power supply to the micro controller will not perform these operations for you, unless it is still possible (i.e. the ramp down is long enough) to capture and handle those events via Low-Side Supervisor (SVSL) and Low-Side Monitor (SVML) interrupts.